# Force aspect ratio with Image Magick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm looking for a command in Image Magick to force an image into a particular aspect ratio. The result should be the original image with the layer expanded to the correct aspect ratio, with the original image in the middle, and any new surrounding space white. How can I do that?

For example, the wide source Image1 generates the following result:

[image: Image1]
[image: Image1 for to 4x3 aspect]

And the tall source Image2 generates this result:

[image]
[image]

In each case, the final processed image has an aspect ratio of 4:3. Otherwise they may have any dimensions. Manually I've been doing a process of: If it's wider than 4:3, set height to width/4×3; else if it's taller than 4:3, set width to height/3×4.

Alternatively, if it's easier, then it would be acceptable for all the output images to be of a fixed size: for example, 640 x 480.

(The desired command will later be used in a batch to process a series of files of various different initial dimensions.)

Comment: Can you draw a little rough diagram/sketch {like you did in earlier post} to make it clearer what you mean

Comment: @Madhubala: Thanks for asking. Adding those now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.png
```

[image]

```
a.jpg
```

[image]

```
 find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \) | \
  while read img; do
   fbname=$(basename "$img")
   magick "$img" -set option:wd "%[fx:(4/3)>(w/h)?(4/3*h):w]" -set option:ht "%[fx:(4/3)>(w/h)?h:(w/(4/3))]" -gravity center -background black -extent "%[wd]x%[ht]" result-"$fbname"
  done
```

---

```
result-a.png
```

[image]

```
result-a.jpg
```

### [image]

> identify a.png

```
a.png PNG 1000x400 1000x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 264165B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

> identify a.jpg

```
a.jpg JPEG 771x1036 771x1036+0+0 8-bit sRGB 186084B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

> identify result-a.jpg

```
result-a.jpg JPEG 1381x1036 1381x1036+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 200001B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

> identify result-a.png

```
result-a.png PNG 1000x750 1000x750+0+0 8-bit sRGB 277529B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: @DanielR.Collins i guess this should work now

Comment: Pretty great! For my DOS batch environment, I had to fix up the looping structure, but the magick kernel here is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: (Maybe answer would be improved by cutting your opening question: obv. I need to switch from manual processing to automated, and I didn't know how to make the math or conditional happen in the magick syntax.)