# Embed image in fixed canvas with Image Magick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm looking for a command in Image Magick to take an arbitrary image (of any aspect ratio), and embed it in an image of a fixed size, growing/shrinking the source image as necessary to fit.

For example, the wide source Image1 generates the following result:

[image]
[image]

And the tall source Image2 generates this result:

[image]
[image]

In each case, the final image is a fixed size, say, 400 x 300 pixels.

(The desired command will later be used in a batch to process a series of files of various different initial dimensions.)

[Compare to this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1651068/force-aspect-ratio-with-image-magick): The current question differs in that it desires a fixed end image size, and possible resizing of the source image (as opposed to keeping the source image unchanged, and establishing a given aspect ratio at the end).

---

I've looked at about a half-dozen tutorial sites at this point, but haven't found any that seemed to address this specific use-case. The following are examples of what I have tried so far.

First, here's a modification of a prior batch file to use variables for specific resizing, but it still results in proportional output and not a fixed output size:

```
REM Fit image for "2 frames + large feature"

set /a fwidth = 870
set /a fheight = 980

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
  set outfile=%%~na-fit
  magick "%%a" -set option:wd "%%[fx:(%fwidth%/%fheight%)>(w/h)?(%fwidth%/%fheight%*h):w]" -set option:ht "%%[fx:(%fwidth%/%fheight%)>(w/h)?h:(w/(%fwidth%/%fheight%))]" -gravity center -background black -extent "%%[wd]x%%[ht]" "!outfile!%%~xa"
)
```

Second, an attempt at forcing a specific output size, but it only serves to crop a part of the original image:

```
REM Fit image to wide format
REM For 5-frame show, 3:2 ratio

set /a fwidth = 300
set /a fheight = 200

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
  set outfile=%%~na-fit
  magick "%%a" -set option:wd "%fwidth%" -set option:ht "%fheight%" -gravity center -background black -extent "%%[wd]x%%[ht]" "!outfile!%%~xa"
)
```

Third, an attempt at using the "convert" operator, initially with a fixed percentage resizing, which entirely fails for a reason I can't detect:

```
REM Fit image to wide format
REM For 5-frame show, 3:2 ratio

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
  set outfile=%%~na-fit
  magick convert "%%a" -resize 25%% "!outfile!%%~xa"
}
```

Fourth, an adjustment to the preceding for a fixed output size, but instead of that output size shrinks the source image to a subset of that size:

```
REM Shrink images to 25% via ImageMagick
REM E.g.: convert image.jpg -resize 25% image-small.jpg

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
  set outfile=%%~na-shrunk
  magick convert "%%a" -resize 300x200 -background black "!outfile!%%~xa"
)
```

So if anyone could point out which is closest to a solution and fix it, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having gotten more time to work on it, here's a batch file that seems to satisfy my requirements (replacing constants with appropriate frame sizes):

```
REM Fit image for "4 frames"

set /a fwidth = 870
set /a fheight = 475

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
  magick convert -size %fwidth%x%fheight% xc:black "%%a" -geometry %fwidth%x%fheight% -gravity center -composite "%%~na-fit%%~xa"
)
```

Comment: This is windows batch file syntax, right?  What does the final expression after -composite expand out to?

Comment: Right. ~na is the primary filename of a, and ~xa is the extension of a. So an initial file of **sample.jpg** produces a resulting file **sample-fit.jpg**.

Answer (score 2):

Linux (bash) based solution that resizes the images in place:

```
#!/bin/bash

SIZE="400x300"

# create the background; could be careful to make sure that background.jpg doesn't already exist
convert -size $SIZE xc:black background.jpg  

for i in `ls *.jpg`
do
convert -resize $SIZE $i - | convert -composite -gravity center background.jpg - $i
done
```

Notable features:

- On my linux distribution `convert` is the ImageMagik command,
- It writes the black background image to disk (drawback),
- but pipes the resized image into the composite function.